# Fail to display correctly newly inserted data in PostGIS on Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have created a postGis store in Geoserver. I have created layers with points and lines and I display them on an OpenLayers based application.
I also use an FME workflow to insert new data to my postGis table. I expected that my geoserver layers would be updated automatically but it didn't happen.

The problem was that I had to set new boundaries in the layers properties. After this I could see some (not all) of my newly inserted data on the map.
In different zoom levels I had different information displayed. For example in the upper zoom lever I could see the whole information but zooming in I was seeing less (see figures).

I thought it might be related with caching. I have used the geoserver interface to seed-generate missing tiles and according to geoserver the process was successful.

Lastly I have restarted geoserver and tomcat7 service without any success either.

When I select layer preview in

[image: whole data]
[image: missing data here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior I've seen before with point data and have not figured out a workaround for the existing layer.  The workaround that I've used in the past is to make a copy of the table in the database, call it something different, and re-create the layer.  When you are at the Bounding Box section, make sure to over estimate the bounding box values slightly (or the possible max extent that the data could grow to).  This will make sure that edge features do not get trimmed off as you zoom in.

[image]

Comment: After all I didn't have to create a copy of the database. I deleted and recreated the layer in geoserver and then it was displayed correctly. Thanks for the tip for the bounding box.